# Microsoft sample WordCount does not work on Local Cluster

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I am trying to learn the development process for Service Fabric
by using one of the popular samples from Microsoft, called WordCount.
I do not have Azure account yet, so I installed the Local Cluster
on my Windows 10. I went through the instructions on Microsoft
website and most of it works. I can see the Cluster Manager with:

```
 http://localhost:19080/Explorer
```

where I can see the application:

```
 fabric:/WordCount   WordCount   1.0.0    OK   Ready
```

From inside the Powershell I can connect to the Local Cluster
and run the cmdlets with output as expected

```
 Get-ServiceFabricApplication
 Get-ServiceFabricService -ApplicationName 'fabric:/WordCount'
 Get-ServiceFabricPartition 'fabric:/WordCount/WordCountService'
```

The problem is when I run

```
 http://localhost:8081/wordcount/index.html
```

the browser does not display anything. It is supposed to display
the counts of words generated by client-side JavaScript 
and processed by ASP.NET Web API. My browser has JavaScript enabled.

I do not know yet enough about the code in the sample but I have its solution with 4 projects loaded in VS2017. I just want to make it work ASAP.

Below I attach a part of console output in my browser (FireFox). Apparently, the JS script is getting

```
 [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 0ms]
```

in response to all requests.

```
POST 
XHR 
http://localhost:8081//wordcount/index.html/api/AddWord/WYVyl [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 0ms]
XML Parsing Error: no root element found
Location: http://localhost:8081//wordcount/index.html/api/AddWord/WYVyl
Line Number 1, Column 1:  WYVyl:1:1
POST 
XHR 
http://localhost:8081//wordcount/index.html/api/AddWord/YcIMv [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 0ms]
XML Parsing Error: no root element found
Location: http://localhost:8081//wordcount/index.html/api/AddWord/YcIMv
Line Number 1, Column 1:  YcIMv:1:1
GET 
XHR 
http://localhost:8081//wordcount/index.html/api/Count [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 0ms]
XML Parsing Error: no root element found
Location: http://localhost:8081//wordcount/index.html   /api/Count?c=0.7465426272903215
Line Number 1, Column 1:  Count:1:1
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you have the right address (http://localhost:8081/wordcount/index.html
)? Are you getting any server side or client side errors. You say "the browser does not display anything" -> So it stays blank and no javascript errors are reported etc,?

Comment: I edited to post to add some more info. The browser is getting [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 0ms] to all requests

Comment: Can you include the link to the sample code?

Comment: I got the samples from   https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-fabric-dotnet-getting-started/tree/classic/Services/WordCount    referenced at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-get-started-with-a-local-cluster  (search in classic)

Comment: Getting 404 on an url like `http://localhost:8081//wordcount/index.html/api/Count` does not surprise me, would expect to see calls to `http://localhost:8081//wordcount/api/Count`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to open up "http://localhost:8081/wordcount/index.html" while you should use "http://localhost:8081/wordcount/". Otherwise the javascript code builds incorrect url to access the services.